# Axiom of foundation implies that bottomless sets are empty?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, terminology, self-learning, axioms

In the notes that I am using to study Set Theory, the Axiom of Foundation is presented as follows:

> **Axiom of Foundation:**
> $$\forall x ( \exists y (y \in x) \rightarrow \exists y ((y \in x) \land \forall z ( (z \in x) \rightarrow \lnot (z \in y)))) $$

According to the textbook, this asserts that bottomless sets are empty. However, I am a bit confused about why that is the case. My interpretation of the statement is that if a set is non-empty, then at least one of its elements does not contain any other elements of the original set.

However, to me, this doesn't feel sufficient to make the claim that bottomless sets are empty, since I'm not really clear on where bottomless sets even feature in this particular formulation of the Axiom of Foundation.

Regarding what exactly we mean by "bottomless", the textbook doesn't define the term before this point, so again, this is potentially another source of my confusion if I am misunderstanding what it is referring to.

I would be grateful for any clarification here.

Comment: You perhaps should define ‘bottomless’

Comment: Perhaps by bottomless you mean a set $x$ such that there is an infinite chain $x_i$ with $x_1 \in x$, $x_2 \in x_1$, etc.  These cannot exist due to the axiom of foundation. But I wouldn't say they are "empty", I'd say they don't exist.

Comment: That was my suspicion of what they meant by bottomless. Why does the formulation of the Axiom of Foundation in the question imply they don't exist though? @JairTaylor

Comment: There's a proof on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#No_infinite_descending_sequence_of_sets_exists).

Comment: The statement of the Axiom of Foundation is different on Wikipedia to the one in the textbook (mentioned in the question) I am using though? Are they equivalent? @JairTaylor

Comment: It's the same really. Wikipedia has it as $ \forall x\,(x\neq \varnothing \rightarrow \exists y(y\in x\ \land y\cap x=\varnothing)$, but $\exists y (y \in x)$ is equivalent to  $x\neq \varnothing$ and $\forall z ( (z \in x) \rightarrow \lnot (z \in y)))$ is equivalent to $y \cap x = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'll have a read through the Wikipedia proof now @JairTaylor

Comment: You are welcome. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition on Wikipedia is equivalent to the one stated in the question by firstly replacing $\exists y (y \in x)$ with $ x \neq \emptyset$ and secondly replacing $\forall z ((z \in x) \rightarrow \lnot (z \in y ))$  with $y \cap x = \emptyset$ (as these are clearly equivalent sentences).

Now we can consider this formulation and directly employ the proof given on Wikipedia (with adjusted notation).

[image]

Which contains further details [in the following link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#No_infinite_descending_sequence_of_sets_exists).